# Not able to understand variable re-declaration

Tags: rust

This code block works correctly:

```
fn main() {
    let x:i32 = 5;
    let x = 6;
    let x = 5;
    assert_eq!(x, 5);
    println!("Success");
}
```

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.81s
     Running `target\debug\learnrust.exe`
Success
```

This gives an assertion error:

```
fn main() {
    let x:i32 = 5;
    let x = 6;
    assert_eq!(x, 5);
    println!("Success");
}
```

```
 Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.06s
     Running `target\debug\learnrust.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:5:5:
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: 6
 right: 5
```

Why isn't the Rust compiler complaining about variable re-declaration?

Comment: You're just defining a new variable with a new name.  The old `x` continues to exist, but it's no longer directly accesisble.

Comment: It's called *shadowing*.